# If $A \otimes B$ is nuclear , then is $B$ nuclear?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are unital $C^*$-algebras, and  that $A \otimes B$ is a nuclear $C^*$-algebra. I want to see if $B$ is nuclear or not.

Since $A \otimes B$ is nuclear, there exist c.c.p maps $\phi_n: A\otimes B \to M_{k_n}(\mathbb{C})$ and $\psi_n: M_{k_n}(\mathbb{C}) \to A \otimes B$ such that $\psi_n \circ \phi_n \to \text{id}$ in the point norm topology.

So I have the following maps: 
 $$B \xrightarrow[j]{b \to 1_A\otimes b}A \otimes B \xrightarrow{\phi_n}M_{k_n}(\mathbb{C})\xrightarrow{\psi_n}A\otimes B \xrightarrow[\pi]{a \otimes b \to b}B$$

Letting $\tilde{\phi_n}=\phi_n \circ j$ and $\tilde{\psi_n}=\pi \circ\psi_n$, we see that $\tilde{\psi_n}\circ \tilde{\phi_n}=\pi\circ(\psi_n \circ \phi_n)\circ j$ and this converges to $\text{id}$ in the point norm topology.

The same thing can be done for $A$ as well. The only question I have is whether $\pi$ is well defined or not? If not, then is there a way of showing this? Or, is there an example of two non-nuclear $C^*$-algebras whose tensor product is nuclear?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated, your $\pi$ cannot  be linear (so, it is not well-defined). If $\pi$ were somehow linear you would have, for any $a\in A$, 
$$
\pi(a\otimes b)=b=\pi(2a\otimes b). 
$$
So $b=\pi(a\otimes b)=\pi(2a\otimes b-a\otimes b)=b-b=0$. Not pretty.

What you need to do is take $\pi$ to be a *slice map*: you fix a state $\phi:A\to\mathbb C$, define $\pi(a\otimes b)=\phi(a)b$, and extend by linearity. The issue is to show that this actually defines a bounded operator. As far as I can tell, this is not obvious. What we can do is identify $B$ with $\mathbb C\otimes B$, so $\phi(a)b$ is identified with $\phi(a)\otimes B$ (this extends properly to an isomorphism of C$^*$-algebras, easy exercise).

So now $\pi$ looks like $\pi(a\otimes b)=\phi(a)\otimes b$, extended by linearity. Then for instance Theorem 3.5.3 in Brown-Ozawa implies that $\pi$ exists and is completely positive, and that $\|\pi\|=\|\phi\|=1$.

With this new $\pi$, your argument works and indeed $A$ and $B$ are nuclear.

Comment: So $A$ and $B$ are both nuclear??

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you. !!!!

Comment: Thanks for both the superb question and answer, but I was just wondering, instead of assuming that both $A$ and $B$ are unital, if we just assume that $A$ is unital, and $A\otimes B$ is nuclear, that should be sufficient to prove $B$ nuclear, right? Also, if neither $A$ nor $B$ is unital, perhaps one can carry out an analogous procedure using an approximate unit? One may run into trouble proving the boundedness of the splice map, perhaps, but perhaps not, because positivity behaves (very) nicely with respect to unitizations... I don't know...

Answer (score 2):

A comment on continuity of the slice map: For $\psi \in S(B)$ we define $\eta_\psi : A \odot B \to A : a \otimes b \mapsto a \psi(b)$. Let $\phi \in S(A)$. Then, for $x = \sum_i a_i \otimes b_i \in A \odot B$, we get 
$$
 \phi(\eta_\psi(x)) = \sum_i \phi(a_i)\psi(b_i) = (\phi \otimes \psi)(x).
$$
If one knows that $\phi \otimes \psi$ defines a state on $A \otimes B$, it immediately follows that $\lVert \eta_\psi(x) \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert$.

If not, it is not hard to show that $\phi \otimes \psi \in S(A \otimes B)$. Indeed, working with the universal representation of $A$ and $B$, one can easily show that 
$$
 \lVert x \rVert = \sup_{\phi \in S(A), \psi \in S(B)} \lVert (\pi_\phi \otimes \pi_\psi)(x) \rVert,
$$
where $\pi_\phi$ resp. $\pi_\psi$ denote the associated GNS representation. If now $x_\phi, x_\psi$ denote the cyclic vectors for the representations $\pi_\phi$ and $\pi_\psi$, we see that 
$$
\lvert  (\phi \otimes \psi)(x)  \rvert = \lvert \langle (\pi_\phi \otimes \pi_\psi)(x)(x_\phi \otimes x_\psi), x_\phi \otimes x_\psi \rangle \lvert \leq \lVert (\pi_\phi \otimes \pi_\psi)(x) \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert.
$$